# How to search in 3 levels of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a Laravel project and have JSON file and want to search in the 3rd level of an array and return of level 1 of array in date array range

[image: this array I want to search]

I use this function:

```
public function search3($array, $key, $value){
$results = array();

if (is_array($array)) {
    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }

    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        $results = array_merge($results, self::search3($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
}

return $results;
}
```

and return with results but not give me this array

[image]

I want function return where is parent of parent of this array:

Comment: I don't understand what you want, can you show the desired result?

Comment: What is the key and value you're searching for?

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting that result. There's no `19-10-2020` in the input array.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for helping

Comment: Please try to use text unless what you need to show is hard to copy/paste as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly; I think you want to search in the third level of an array for a 'from' + date or a 'to' + date combination, and then return the hotels (that are two levels above the matched data) that have a match for the given combination.

How about this?

```
function search3($hotels, $key, $value){
    $results = array();

    foreach ($hotels as $hotelKey => $hotelProperties) {

        foreach ($hotelProperties['availability'] as $availabilityKey => $range) {

            if (isset($range[$key]) && $range[$key] == $value) {
                $results[$hotelKey] = $hotels[$hotelKey];
            }

        }

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Update for finding hotels that are available within a given date range, given a from and a to date:

```
function search3($hotels, $from, $to){

    $format = 'd-m-Y';
    $from = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $from);
    $to = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $to);

    $results = array();

    foreach ($hotels as $hotelKey => $hotelProperties) {

        foreach ($hotelProperties['availability'] as $range) {

            $availableFrom = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $range['from']);
            $availableTo = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $range['to']);

            if ($from >= $availableFrom && $to <= $availableTo) {
                $results[$hotelKey] = $hotelProperties;
            }

        }

    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: YES you understand me very well and code is working now @Stanzi1791

Comment: Thank you very much @Stanzi1791

Comment: what if i want to add date"to" and want to add grater or less than date ?

Comment: yes but i need to make date only d-m-y not d-m-y H-M-S

Comment: its worked after edit if 
if ($from >= $availableFrom && $to <= $availableTo) {
                $results[$hotelKey] = $hotelProperties;
            }
TO:
            if ($from <= $availableFrom && $to >= $availableTo) {
             $results[$hotelKey] = $hotelProperties;

        
            }

Comment: Thanks for your help